# How to check particular VMware VM is not currently running in the task using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I need to check particular VMware VM is currently in the recent task like CLone_task, Migrate_VMTask,.etc and also skip that VM before VM migration starts..

I have tried the below code:

```
PS> Get-Task (Get-VM -Name VM1) | Select State

Get-Task : Cannot bind parameter 'Status'. Cannot convert the "nalb00cava3"
value of type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Inventory.VirtualMachineImpl"
to type "VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Types.V1.TaskState".
At line:1 char:10
+ Get-Task (Get-VM -Name nalb00cava3) | Select State
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Task], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetTask
```

Comment: `Get-Task`'s [documentation](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/64ee9c63-6647-46bd-8685-32b97590c294/b5861550-655c-4498-ba7e-8b24b492bf31/doc/Get-Task.html) suggests the command doesn't seem to have a parameter that accepts a VM.

Comment: So Is not possible to get-task for particular VM? @Ansgar Wiechers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for, the final pipe is where you would define the specific VM.

```
Get-Task | ?{$_.ObjectId -match 'VirtualMachine'} | Select @{N='VM';E={(Get-View -Id $_.ObjectId).Name }},State,Description | where  {$_.VM -eq "VM1"}
```

It filters on ObjectId from Get-Task, then referencing the Id, determines the VM names, and finally filters on the VM you define.